# Django templates not updating after database changes via admin

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django v2.2 admin to change the information on my database but after I change it and refresh the page, the new data is not there, only the old data.

A fix for this if I restart the server, the templates can now fetch the new data that I input.

views.py

```
# template with context
class Home(TemplateView):
    template = 'home.html'
    context = { 'bar': Baby.objects.all() }

     def get(self, request):
         return render(request, self.template, self.context)
```

home.html

```
{% for foo in bar %}
    {{ foo.name }}
    {{ foo.cost }}
{% endfor %}
```

How I can get the new data by refreshing the page and not restarting the server?

Comment: Check cache settings and middleware list.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I can't find any cache settings in my settings.py.

Comment: Really you should use a ListView and set the model or queryset attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others mentioned, use `get_context_data()` method is good idea, because `ContextMixin` is parent class (not base class, but part of `TemplateView`'s `__mro__` **Method Resolution Order**) of `TemplateView` which is responsible to pass data from view to template. But, if you want to **render** template manually using `get()` method, You should hit on database on every `GET` request (in your case).

```
class Home(TemplateView):
    template = 'home.html'

     def get(self, request):
        self.context = {'bar': Baby.objects.all()}
        return render(request, self.template, self.context)
```

Your code does not work, because `static` variables are initialized only once. In your case `context` was static variable.

Hope, it helps you.

Comment: This really helps.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try this?

```
class Home(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['bar'] = Baby.objects.all()
        return context
```